# Get file path through type=file

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html element input type file. I am getting the multiple file names using this code:

```
<input id="inputAddVideo" onchange="AddVideo(this.id)" type="file" name="upload" multiple/>

 var files = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        alert('path: ' + files[i].path);
        var filename = files[i].name.split('.');
}
```

Now at the same time, how can I retrieve path of each file using javascript?

Comment: By path you mean the path of the file on the user's computer?

Comment: Yes. from the input type 'file'

Comment: So, is there any way I can make playlist through javascript. I want to select file whether it is through my root folder. I want to get file paths ?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to access this via JavaScript; as a security precaution the browser will  expose the file name to you, but nothing else about the local file system.

Comment: I have done some searching to upload a file to a specific folder. But when I click submit button, it does not upload the file 

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/VideoFiles/" method="post">
            <input id="inputAddVideo" onchange="AddVideo(this.id)" type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

This is a built in security measure by the browser creators, so private information about local file paths cannot be seen.