# How to alert the path name?

Tags: angularjs

I need to alert the path name by clicking the link tag but it's not working for me. Since I am new to `angular` I am confused about where I went wrong. Can somebody help me with this?

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@2.0.0-alpha.20" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.20" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.20/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ProductCtrl">
    <form name="frmMain" id="frmMain">
      <input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile" />
      <a href="#" ngclick="showFileName()">Show Name</a>
    </form>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function ProductCtrl($scope) {

$scope.showFileName= function(){

   var fil = document.getElementById("myFile");
   alert(fil.value); 


}
}
</script>
  </body>

</html>
```

And here is my plnkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/Cir7Ardx3OVvwPWYJNNv?p=preview

Comment: 1) You mis-spelled ng-click. 2) The URL for angular.js is incorrect. It should be `https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.20/angular2.js`

Comment: Ya i did as u said but there is no response ....

Comment: Ya i did as u said but there is no response .wat i  need is wen i click on the link  tag the path name should be alerted.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure. Even with those changes the console says "angular is undefined". You're using angular 2, which has some significant differences to 1. Did you start from a working angular 2 example?

Comment: Actually  the code was in javascript  foramat  but  i tried to do tat in Angular format.... it works perfectly in javascript

Comment: can  u send me the plunker of urs which u tried.....

Comment: I only modified your plunker with those 2 changes that I mentioned. The next problem is that the console says angular is undefined. Perhaps someone else has an idea about that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to alert the path name in the alert box in angular js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101843/how-to-alert-the-path-name-in-the-alert-box-in-angular-js)

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your previous question?

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your Plunkr demo and forked it here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/YuinLcjb6OU7VsdSMca9?p=preview

First, I wasn't sure if you intended to target the unstable 2.0 version or not, so I changed it to target the latest stable release of AngularJS (1.3.15). Next, I moved your script to the script.js file and formatted your controller properly.

Now the HTML looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ProductCtrl">
    <form name="frmMain" id="frmMain">
      <input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile" />
      <a href="#" ng-click="showFileName()">Show Name</a>
    </form>

    <hr />
    {{ name }}
  </body>

</html>
```

and your script looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

  .controller("ProductCtrl", ProductCtrl);

function ProductCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.showFileName= function(){
     var fil = document.getElementById("myFile");
     alert(fil.value); 
  };
}
```

This is half the battle: making sure that your framework is working correctly.  Now, how to show the full path of the selected file? Here are a few links to help you with that (or not, actually):

- [How to get the full path of the file from a file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176377/how-to-get-the-full-path-of-the-file-from-a-file-input)
- [Get file path through type=file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342685/get-file-path-through-type-file?lq=1)

Comment: From the quick research I did on the full file path, it appears to be a security issue.